# Unable to get my html after EJS to display when the file is rendered

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, ejs

Hello Im not the best when it comes to using ejs so apologies if this is a stupid question. Im  having a really difficult time figuring out why the html after my EJS data is not displaying, once I start my server. Im not sure if missing something after the ejs or if im completly using it incorrectly,  Any help would be much appreciated.

Below you can find my code

```
 <!-- Movie Section -->
        <section class="movie-section-container">
            <div class="category-banner">
                <h1 class="category-name">POPULAR</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="movies-container">

                <% movieData.items.forEach(movie=> {%>
                    <div class="movie-card-filter">
                        <div class="movie-card">
                            <span class="rating">
                                <%=movie.imDbRating%><i class="fa-solid fa-star"></i>
                            </span>
                            <div class="poster-container">
                                <img src=<%=movie.image%> alt=<%=movie.fullTitle%>>
                            </div>
                            <div class="movie-info">
                                <h5 class="movie-name">
                                    <%=movie.title%>
                                </h5>
                                <div class="details">
                                    <div class="year-date">
                                        <span><span class="year">
                                                <%=movie.year%>
                                            </span>.<span class="runtime">127 min</span></span>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="platform">
                                        <span>Movie</span>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <%})%>
                        <!-- Movie Info Overlay -->

                        <section class="movie-overlay">
                            <div class="movie-details-container">
                                <div class="details-btns">
                                    <a href="#" class="official-page">OFFICIAL PAGE</a>
                                    <button class="close-btn">
                                        <i class="fa-solid fa-circle-xmark"></i>
                                    </button>
                                </div>
                                <div class="movie-details">
                                    <div class="movie-poster">
                                        <img src="https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500/AeyiuQUUs78bPkz18FY3AzNFF8b.jpg"
                                            alt="movie-poster">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="info">
                                        <h2 class="movie-info-name">Fullmetal Alchemist: The Final Alchemy</h2>
                                        <h4 class="movie-info-release-date">Release date: 2022-06-24</h4>
                                        <div class="movie-info-ratings">
                                            <span>rating: 6.3 <i class="fa-solid fa-star"></i></span>
                                            <span class="movie-info-votes">all votes: 109</span>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="movie-info-genre">Action</div>
                                        <div class="movie-info-plot">
                                            <h4>Plot: The Elric brothers' long and winding journey comes to a close in
                                                this epic finale,
                                                where they must face off against an unworldly, nationwide threat.</h4>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="trailer">
                                    <div class="line"></div>
                                    <h3 class="trailer-title">Trailer:</h3>
                                    <iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/cqj4u6eyDq8" title="YouTube video player"
                                        frameborder="0"
                                        allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture"
                                        allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Answer (score 1):

Ended up using a partial to fill in the rest of the information and this worked out for me, I'm not sure if this is the best practice but this was all that I was finding as a solution.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I see the code is not full. if your header and footer is in other file then add this to this file..

```
<%- include("header") -%> // it should contain content upper part.

<%- include("footer") -%> // it should contain content lower part.
```

if your code in partials then follow this one:

```
<%- include("partials/header") -%> // it should contain content upper part.

<%- include("partials/footer") -%> // it should contain content lower part.
```